How do I load user defined application properties as annotation values for an application via a wrapper for Spring AMQP?
I'm new to Spring and am trying to write a wrapper for Rabbitmq with Spring. I intend to use everything provided by Spring AMQP, the purpose of this is to only configure common defaults, define tracing, error handling etc so I can write applications using this library and not have to worry about getting everything 'right'.
I expect this to be very lightweight and would like to do it the Spring way. I'm focused on a consumer right now.
Intention
my wrapper
I would like to provide only an annotation ( I've looked into it then being a meta-annotation for @RabbitListener.
I would like to do something like this : ( I've added what I've done so far below )
public @interface MyAwesomeListener {
  String consumer(); 
}

application
An app using my wrapper would then simply provide the configuration as :
configuration
Provided by the application in it's properties file ( please ignore the syntax )
I want to make the consumers field to be mandatory, within each consumer, certain fields will also be mandatory (for eg queue)
consumers:
  myConsumer:
    queue: foo
    exchange: fooEx
    binding: fooExRK
    prefetch: 2
    minThreads: 5
  anotherConsumer:
    queue: bar
    exchange: barEx
    binding: barExRK

using my wrapper
@MyLib.MyAwesomeListener(consumer='myConsumer')
public void consumeMessages1_2_3(Object object) {
  //application's own way to consumer a message
}

The idea is all someone writing an application needs to do is:

provide the right config under their own 'consumer' under the consumers property in their application
Decorate their own method with the common annotation MyAwesomeListener


what I expect
When an application decorates their method with MyAwesomeListener, I would  like to read the provided value from the annotation 's property (consumer) then find it's configuration ( well defined valid properties within each 'consumer' ) in the application's `application.properties. Then pass on those values to override any configured defaults I have ( for example connectionFactory/other defaults etc. ) and ultimately 'call' it's meta-annotation - the @RabbitListener. So it's like a bring your own consumer.
I can devise a default connection factory, prefetch counts, always override the errorHandler etc. so I don't have to do these in every application.
If the provided consumer or 'consumers' field does not exist, I'd like to raise a compilation/runtime error.
what I've tried
In my library
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactoryConsumer") // my predefined factory
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MyAwesomeListener {

        @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "bindings")
        QueueBinding[] queueBinding();

        @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "id")
        String name();


    }

In my application
    @MyLib.MyAwesomeListener(
            queueBinding =
                    {@QueueBinding
                            (value = @Queue(value = "${consumer.myConsumer.queue}",
                                    durable = "true"),
                            exchange = @Exchange(value = "${consumer.myConsumer.exchange}",
                                    type = "direct", durable = "true"),
                            key = "${consumer.myConsumer.routingKey}")}
            , name = "myConsumer")
)
    public Boolean consumeMessages1_2_3(MyProperties myProperties) {
        //MyProperties is a class extending Serializable
        //print / consumer ... do something ...
        return true;

    }

What does not work?

Users have to specify so many things when decorating with MyAwesomeListener - I would like to control these via a configuration
Cannot default - to say min threads are 6 unless overidden
Cannot use variables provided to the annotation - there's a name property name, I'd like to use it to provide the connection name as well as the id property of RabbitListener ( spring amqp provides connectionFactory.setConnectionNameStrategy(connectionFactory -> "MY_CONNECTION") ) - these are static and cannot be loaded into the method(MyLib.class.getAnnotation(MyAwesomeListener.class).name()
I have to repeat this if I need more consumers
Defeats the purpose of common defaults altogether

The question?
I don't believe this should be as hard as I'm making it out to be in my mind, what's the obvious,simplest solution that I'm missing?

What you are asking is really not possible with existing infrastructure.
The RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is not aware of your custom consumer annotation attribute.
You probably can come up with some extension for that RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to parse your custom attribute and populate a @RabbitListener from there to call:
protected Collection<Declarable> processAmqpListener(RabbitListener rabbitListener, Method method, Object bean,
        String beanName) {

in the end.
Another way is to create a MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint manually and call this.registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint, factory); for that.
I might miss something else, but this is very hard question which just cannot be solved easy with existing infrastructure and utilities.
I wish Java would never introduce annotations since they don't scale very well with inheritance and encapsulation.

Thank you for getting back to me!
I at the very least feel better with regards to feeling that this was too hard.
The insight is helpful, I'll try it out and report back here.
I'm wondering if this is a viable thing to try however and if this is a generic thing other people might have faced / will face as well
